# Rotatable Bounding Box

Tags: object-detection, bounding-box

I have checked out many methods like Yolov3, SSD (single shot detector), etc with very promising result in detecting a rectangular box around the object, But could not find any method, which outputs rotated bounding box.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B2a4.png)

can someone guide me with the resources to get a green colour Bounding Box instead of red colour in the image which I have attached

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is Faster RCNN rotation invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295716/is-faster-rcnn-rotation-invariant)